# Using HTML,JS and CSS in spring mvc application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

> I dont want to use **JSP** and instead use **HTML,CSS and JAVASCRPIT** . 
>   I dont't want to use any front end technology like **AngularJS**but only only **AJAX** for communicating with **backend**. I have only one page as **index.html** and few **.js and .css files**. But I am not able to configure spring mvc to use these html and other js and css files.
>
> Can somebody help me with the project structure and the configurations for it.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your project structure and codes...

Comment: I wasnt able to use html.. Javascript in my project. So finally i made my backend fully restful and for front end i made another project and communicated with the backend using ajax.

Comment: I am still looking for a way to use static resources in the spring app. But since today the standard is using restful apis. I am ok with my new approach as well.. But if someone can still help me with my question. I will be glad.

Comment: Why don't you user `jQuery`? There are lots of thing you can accomplish with it.

Comment: Yeah. I will in future. Its been only 2 weeks for me since i have started doing some web development. Before tjat i only knew java core. So currently  i want to learn javascript before moving forward nto any frameworks.

Comment: https://github.com/mohitkumar20/springRestApp  and https://github.com/mohitkumar20/springFrontEnd . this is how i jave configured my web app now.